# Maven + Cobertura: Error Generating Site and Checking for Build Parameters

Tags: maven, cobertura

I have configured the Maven build of my project to fail if code coverage limits as reported by Cobertura are not met. Works fine. I've tried now to generate and link in the Cobertura report when I use Maven's site generation tool, but I get this error when doing `mvn site`:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project kb-framework: 
failed to get report for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.7:instrument 
(cobertura-check) on project kb-framework: 
Unable to prepare instrumentation directory. source and destination are the same directory.
```

With the pom.xml as configured below, I can:

1. Run `mvn verify` and see the build pass/fail
2. Remove the cobertura-check execution and `mvn site` works. No checking is done during build.
3. Add an execution to the build segment with the cobertura goal, generate the HTML report during the verify phase and still use the check goal.

It appears that the tests and instrumentation are run twice when I do `mvn site` as configured.

It also appears that this error arises out of the fact that the second instrumentation is being done. If I replace the cobertura check goal with the cobertura report generation goal, build still fails with the same message. So the check goal is not the problem, instrumentation is.

So: can anyone help me configure my pom.xml to pass/fail the build on `mvn verify` AND generate and link in the HTML report while doing `mvn site`?

Here are relevant portions of pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <configuration>
        <check>
          <branchRate>85</branchRate>
          <lineRate>90</lineRate>
          <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
          <totalBranchRate>90</totalBranchRate>
          <totalLineRate>90</totalLineRate>
          <packageBranchRate>90</packageBranchRate>
          <packageLineRate>90</packageLineRate>
        </check>
      <instrumentation>
        <excludes>
          <!-- some excludes in here -->
        </excludes>
      </instrumentation>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>cobertura-clean</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>cobertura-check</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin> 
</plugins>

<reporting>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
     <formats>
       <format>html</format>
       <format>xml</format>
     </formats>
    </configuration>
  </plugin> 
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently I needed to use the clean goal during site generation, then I can use whatever goals I want during the build phase. I added a reportSet block to pom.xml as below; now I can get a pass/fail during `mvn verify` and link in the report during `mvn site` without error messages.

pom.xml (build phase left as described in the question):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
     <formats>
       <format>html</format>
       <format>xml</format>
     </formats>
    </configuration>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <id>cobertura-report</id>
        <reports>
          <report>clean</report>
          <report>cobertura</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets> 
  </plugin>
```